# Image going to second page of PDF VB.Net iTextSharp

Tags: vb.net, image, pdf, itext

Here is my code:

```
                'Make a new image object
            Dim ImagePath = "C:\Mickosis\Class Manager\Logo.jpg"
            Dim Img = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(ImagePath)
            Img.SetAbsolutePosition(464, 710)
            wri.DirectContent.AddImage(Img)

            Dim ImagePath1 = "C:\Mickosis\Class Manager\AdU.jpg"
            Dim Img1 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(ImagePath1)
            Img1.SetAbsolutePosition(29, 710)
            wri.DirectContent.AddImage(Img1)
```

The problem is that if the PDF only has one page, it will appear on the upper left and right of the page - that's correct. But when there's too much text inside and it needs to have a second page, the images will appear on the next page rather than the first page only. Any solutions would be great. Thank you!

Here is what's happening: (One page PDF file)
[image]

When it has two pages:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible solutions:

1. Add your images first. That is: before you add any other content. This way, they will always be on the first page.
2. Add your images in a page event, more specifically in the `OnEndPage()` method. However: check if you are on the first page before you add them. If `writer.PageNumber` isn't equal to 1, don't add any images.